# Why does java allow NPE

Tags: java

How come `javac` doesn't emit error on this code?

```
private static int compute(int v) {
    return v == 0 ? null : v;
}
```

Surely, `compute(0)` will throw `NullPointerException`. I would expect the java compiler to prevent this by doing some basic static code analysis, just like it would prevent

```
private static int compute(int v) {
    if (v == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return v;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why does java allow NPE?*

To indicate an **exceptional** condition (and allow the **programmer** to potentially *recover*).

In your example, Java allows both [*autoboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [*unboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). The `null` boxes the `int` to an `Integer` (which is then *unboxed* to an `int`).

Comment: Oh I see. `v == 0 ? null : v` induces Integer type and it tricks the compiler. I still think it's stupid.

Comment: This is one reason why using the ternary operator is generally considered bad practice by some people. Many developer new to Java see it and think it's an opportunity to reduce verbosity in reality it's a great way to cause hard to find bugs.